# Solving 5SUM in O(n^3) with strict memory limits

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, hash, hashtable

I need a way to solve the classic 5SUM problem without hashing or with a memory efficient way of hashing.

The problem asks you to find how many subsequences in a given array of length N have the sum equal to S

Ex:

```
Input
6 5
1 1 1 1 1 1
Output
6
```

The restrictions are:

```
N <= 1000 ( size of the array )
S <= 400000000 ( the sum of the subsequence )
Memory usage <= 5555 kbs
Execution time 2.2s
```

I'm pretty sure the excepted complexity is O(N^3). Due to the memory limitations hashing doesn't provide an actual O(1) time.

The best I got was 70 points using this code. ( I got TLE on 6 tests )

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#define MAX 1003
#define MOD 10472

using namespace std;

ifstream in("take5.in");
ofstream out("take5.out");

vector<pair<int, int>> has[MOD];
int v[MAX];
int pnt;
vector<pair<int, int>>::iterator it;

inline void ins(int val) {
    pnt = val%MOD;
    it = lower_bound(has[pnt].begin(), has[pnt].end(), make_pair(val, -1));
    if(it == has[pnt].end() || it->first != val) {
        has[pnt].push_back({val, 1});
        sort(has[pnt].begin(), has[pnt].end());
        return;
    }
    it->second++;
}

inline int get(int val) {
    pnt = val%MOD;
    it = lower_bound(has[pnt].begin(), has[pnt].end(), make_pair(val, -1));
    if(it == has[pnt].end() || it->first != val)
        return 0;
    return it->second;
}

int main() {

    int n,S;
    int ach = 0;
    int am = 0;
    int rez = 0;
    in >> n >> S;

    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        in >> v[i];

    sort(v+1, v+n+1);

    for(int i = n; i >= 1; i--) {

        if(v[i] > S)
            continue;

        for(int j = i+1; j <= n; j++) {
            if(v[i]+v[j] > S)
                break;
            ins(v[i]+v[j]);
        }

        int I = i-1;

        if(S-v[I] < 0)
            continue;

        for(int j = 1; j <= I-1; j++) {

            if(S-v[I]-v[j] < 0)
                break;

            for(int k = 1; k <= j-1; k++) {

                if(S-v[I]-v[j]-v[k] < 0)
                    break;

                ach = S-v[I]-v[j]-v[k];
                rez += get(ach);

            }
        }
    }

    out << rez << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `N` in constraints? Size of array?

Comment: Yea, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: and what is the constraint for `S`? Sum? Also, why are u using `mod`?

Comment: For some reason I forgot about S too... And what do you mean by why am I using mod?

Comment: Can you just make a 400,000,000 boolean array/bit set? Use n^2 time to save the values of all pairs, and then use n^3 lookups to solve the problem. Alternatively compute the 1000,000 pairs and sort them.

Comment: The questions asks how many subsequences are there that sum up to S, a boolean array would only tell me if there exists one and, I'm adding more pairs every step so I would need to sort it every time which would make the upper bound for the complexity O(N^3logN) if I understand what you're saying correctly.

Comment: Do you mean subsequence or subset ? As classical as it may be, I found no description of a 5SUM that looks like your problem.

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2973/generalised-3sum-k-sum-problem

Comment: You can use a Bloom filter as a probabilistic hash set -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter. Maybe this helps.

Comment: @GabiPurcaru I've implemented a probabilistic test to check whether or not the item is in the hash and it improved to execution time by a bit ( I'm getting 80 points now ) but it's not quite there yet.

Comment: 5555 kbs means 5555 kB or 694 kB?

Comment: @AntonínLejsek 5555 kilobytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it can be done. We are looking for all subsets of 5 items in the array `arr` with the correct `SUM`. We have array with indexes `0..N-1`. Third item of those five can have index `i` in range `2..N-3`. We cycle through all those indexes. For every index `i` we generate all combinations of two numbers for index in range `0..i-1` on the left of index `i` and all combinations of two numbers for index in the range `i+1..N-1` on the right of index `i`. For every index `i` there are less than `N*N` combinations on the left plus on the right side. We would store only sum for every combination, so it would not be more than 1000 * 1000 * 4 = 4MB.

Now we have two sequences of numbers (the sums) and task is this: Take one number from first sequence and one number from second sequence and get sum equal to `Si = SUM - arr[i]`. How many combinations are there? To do it efficiently, sequences have to be sorted. Say first is sorted ascending and have numbers `a, a, a, b, c ,...`. Second is sorted descending and have numbers `Z, Z, Y, X, W, ...`. If `a + Z > Si` then we can throw `Z` away, because we do not have smaller number to match. If `a + Z < Si` we can throw away `a`, because we do not have bigger number to match. And if `a + Z = Si` we have 2 * 3 = 6 new combinations and get rid of both `a` and `Z`. If we get sorting for free, it is nice O(N^3) algorithm.

While sorting is not for free, it is O(N * N^2 * log(N^2)) = O(N^3 * log(N)). We need to do sorting in linear time, which is not possible. Or is it? In index `i+1` we can reuse sequences from index `i`. There are only few new combinations for `i+1` - only those that involve number `arr[i]` together with some number from index `0..i-1`. If we sort them (and we can, because there are not `N*N` of them, but `N` at most), all we need is to merge two sorted sequences. And that can be done in linear time. We can even avoid sorting completely if we sort `arr` at the beginning. We just merge.

For second sequence the merging does not involve adding but removing, but it is very simmilar.

The implementation seems to work, but I expect there is off by one error somewhere ;-)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


int Generate(int arr[], int i, int sums[], int N, int NN)
{
    int p1 = 0;
    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < i - 1; ++i1)
    {
        int ai = arr[i1];
        for (int i2 = i1 + 1; i2 < i; ++i2)
        {
            sums[p1++] = ai + arr[i2];
        }
    }
    sort(sums, sums + p1);
    return p1;
}

int Combinations(int n, int sums[], int p1, int p2, int NN)
{
    int cnt = 0;
    int a = 0;
    int b = NN - p2;

    do
    {
        int state = sums[a] + sums[b] - n;

        if (state > 0) { ++b; }
        else if (state < 0) { ++a; }
        else
        {
            int cnta = 0;
            int lastA = sums[a];
            while (a < p1 && sums[a] == lastA) { a++; cnta++; }

            int cntb = 0;
            int lastB = sums[b];
            while (b < NN && sums[b] == lastB) { b++; cntb++; }

            cnt += cnta * cntb;
        }
    } while (b < NN && a < p1);

    return cnt;
}

int Add(int arr[], int i, int sums[], int p2, int N, int NN)
{
    int ii = N - 1;
    int n = arr[i];
    int nn = n + arr[ii--];
    int ip = NN - p2;
    int newP2 = p2 + N - i - 1;

    for (int p = NN - newP2; p < NN; ++p)
    {
        if (ip < NN && (ii < i || sums[ip] > nn))
        {
            sums[p] = sums[ip++];
        }
        else
        {
            sums[p] = nn;
            nn = n + arr[ii--];
        }
    }
    return newP2;
}

int Remove(int arr[], int i, int sums[], int p1)
{
    int ii = 0;
    int n = arr[i];
    int nn = n + arr[ii++];
    int pp = 0;
    int p = 0;
    for (; p < p1 - i; ++p)
    {
        while (ii <= i && sums[pp] == nn)
        {
            ++pp;
            nn = n + arr[ii++];
        }
        sums[p] = sums[pp++];
    }
    return p;
}

int main() {
    ifstream in("take5.in");
    ofstream out("take5.out");

    int N, SUM;
    in >> N >> SUM;

    int* arr = new int[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        in >> arr[i];

    sort(arr, arr + N);

    int NN = (N - 3) * (N - 4) / 2 + 1;
    int* sums = new int[NN];
    int combinations = 0;
    int p1 = 0;
    int p2 = 1;

    for (int i = N - 3; i >= 2; --i)
    {
        if (p1 == 0)
        {
            p1 = Generate(arr, i, sums, N, NN);
            sums[NN - 1] = arr[N - 1] + arr[N - 2];
        }
        else
        {
            p1 = Remove(arr, i, sums, p1);
            p2 = Add(arr, i + 1, sums, p2, N, NN);
        }

        combinations += Combinations(SUM - arr[i], sums, p1, p2, NN);
    }

    out << combinations << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice!!
Thank you. :)